# HTML tabs with java script

Tags: javascript, html, tabs

I have this fly-out menu. This is the HTML:

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li class="tab"><a class="active" href='#sw_operations'>Software Operations</a></li>
    <li class="tab"><a href='#software'>Software</a></li>
    <li class="tab"><a href='#fac_staff'>Fac/Staff Members</a></li>
    <li class="tab"><a href='#vendor'>Vendors</a></li>
    <li class="tab"><a href='#admin'>Admin</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href='#users'><span>Users</span></a></li>
            <li><a href='#variables'><span>Variables</span></a></li>
            <li><a href='#Reports'><span>Reports</span></a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

This is the JS:

```
$('.tab a').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".tab a").removeClass('active');
    $(".tab a").parent().removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    target = $(this).attr('href');
    $('.tab-content > div').not(target).hide();
    $(target).fadeIn(600);
});
```

What I would like to do is, when the user hits the #admin tab, it goes by default to the #users tab directly. The #admin tab is just empty, that's why right now it just goes to a blank page.

How do I do it in javascript within that JS part??

Thanks :)

Comment: What do you mean by go to the #users tab when the user presses the #admin tab? That doesn't make sense to me from what I understand...

Comment: I have 5 main tabs. The last tab named "admin". Inside "admin" tab I have 3 children tabs, "users", variables and "reports". So when the user hovers over "admin", it gives him the 3 children tabs. When he presses on each, it goes to the corresponding tab. But, if the user hits on the parent tab,  "admin" itself, I want it just to go to the first child tab which is "users".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just assign it the same href as the users tab...

```
<ul class="nav">
<li class="tab"><a class="active" href='#sw_operations'>Software Operations</a></li>
<li class="tab"><a href='#software'>Software</a></li>
<li class="tab"><a href='#fac_staff'>Fac/Staff Members</a></li>
<li class="tab"><a href='#vendor'>Vendors</a></li>
<li class="tab"><a href='#users'>Admin</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href='#users'><span>Users</span></a></li>
        <li><a href='#variables'><span>Variables</span></a></li>
        <li><a href='#Reports'><span>Reports</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That works just fine. I have another thing to do. When the user hits a child tab, I want to add that specific tab to active class as well as it's parent tab using the JS part. I tried doing it, but couldn't figure it out. Right now, it adds only the child tab to active class. Please help :)

Comment: @MazinAliKarar can you open it in a new question? I will answer it then:) just give me the topic of the new question and I will answer it...

Comment: This is the question title "Adding HTML children and parent tabs to active class using javascript". Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Why not just set users as href of the admin tab ?

```
<ul class="nav">
<li class="tab"><a class="active" href='#sw_operations'>Software Operations</a></li>
<li class="tab"><a href='#software'>Software</a></li>
<li class="tab"><a href='#fac_staff'>Fac/Staff Members</a></li>
<li class="tab"><a href='#vendor'>Vendors</a></li>
<li class="tab"><a href='#users'>Admin</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href='#users'><span>Users</span></a></li>
        <li><a href='#variables'><span>Variables</span></a></li>
        <li><a href='#Reports'><span>Reports</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: Thanks alot. That works just fine. I have another thing to do. When the user hits a child tab, I want to add that specific tab to active class as well as it's parent tab using the JS part. I tried doing it, but couldn't figure it out. Right now, it adds only the child tab to active class. Please help :)